# Facing "onMeasure() did not set the measured dimension by calling setMeasuredDimension()" error when using gridview

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm using gridview plugin in my app. (https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-grid-view)

After adding the following lines in my references, I am facing an error:

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/ios.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android.d.ts" />
```

The error:

> file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view.js:58:124: JS ERROR Error: onMeasure() did not set the measured dimension by calling setMeasuredDimension() Label(174)

Here is the code snippet

```js
<GridLayout class="page">
 <GridView [items]="watches" colWidth="49%" rowHeight="280">
   <ng-template let-item="item">
  <FlexboxLayout class="watch-item">
    <Label text="Hi"></Label>
  </FlexboxLayout>
   </ng-template>
 </GridView>
 </GridLayout>
```

I have tried different layouts, but the error is the same.

I was wondering how can this be solved?

Thanks

Comment: Is it a issue with iOS / Android?

Comment: It is with iOS, I haven't checked android yet

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a [known issue](https://github.com/PeterStaev/NativeScript-Grid-View/issues/43) with the plugin when using with Angular.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if that issue is related to mine, however I found the cause of the issue. I changed back tns-core-modules to ^4.2.0 and tns-platform-declarations to ^4.0.0 from 5 and the issue is fixed. It seems the plugin is not compatible with latest updates of tns

Comment: If you use just a label, then you get the above error. If you use other components like TextField or simply just the StackLayout it never gets rendered. So I believe the core issue here is same.

Answer (score -1):

it looks like you're not importing the namespace

add: `xmlns:gv="nativescript-grid-view"`
to your page declaration
then prefix your `<GridView ...>` with `<gv:GridView ...>`

Comment: That's NativeScript Core way of doing things, its `registerElement` with Angular.